# How to constrain an object's motion with the Simple Motion Actuator

Tags: game-engine, constraints

I've defined a Logic Bricks Simple Motion Actuator which responds to keyboard input to move an object along the Z axis. It works fine, but I want the object to be limited to move from 0.0 to 5.0 along the Z axis. Once it reaches one of those limits I don't want it to move anymore.

I tried adding an Object Constraint, which limits my ability to move it in the editor, but that constraint is not imposed by the game engine.

What do I need to do to impose that constraint on the game engine?

Answer (score 0):

Constraints in game engine are defined using logic bricks or Python.

See the example file using the Constraint actuator: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48429

BGE Manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/constraint.html#location-constraint